# Display a dictionary with a custom dataClass

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I have been trying to display values and keys in a combobox, but so far its working only if the dictionary is  I have a dictionary of

```
   Data = Dictionary<string, Option<double>>
```

The Option is simply to allow null value(Optional in case its unavailable at retrieval).

at the moment am using this, to display just the values

```
   var list = (from entry in Data select entry.Value).ToList();
   DistanceSelectionForm.DistanceList = list.SelectMany(r =>    
    r).ToArray().ToSeq();
  public ISeq<double> radarDistanceList {
  set {
    DistanceComboBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(value,null);
    }
  }
```

of thats what I tried use, but didnt work

```
ComboBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(value,null);
ComboBox.DisplayMember = "Key"
ComboBox.ValueMember = "Value";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use a list of objects instead of dictionary. every object will have a key and a value, Which you will use for DisplayMember and ValueMember.
here is a full example of a form with only combo box:

```
public class myClass
{
  private string key;
  private string val;

  public string Key
  {
     get
     {
        return key;
     }
     set
     {
        key = value;
     }
  }

  public string Value
  {
     get
     {
        return val;
     }
     set
     {
        val = value;
     }
  }

  public myClass(string newKey, string newVal)
  {
     key = newKey;
     val = newVal;
  }
}

   public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  List<myClass> list = new List<myClass>(); 

  public Form1()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     list.Add(new myClass("a","aa"));
     list.Add(new myClass("b", "bb"));
     list.Add(new myClass("v", "vv"));
     comboBox1.DataSource = list;
     comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Key";
     comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
  }
}
```

Comment: you mean List<Tuple<string,Option<double>>> ?

Comment: wouldn't that be the same current problem ? what's the difference ?